# Can I get query params from GET-method and put into response?

Tags: mocking, query-string, wiremock

Can I get query params from GET-method and put into response?

For example, I have mock:

```
"request": {
  "method": "GET",
  "urlPathPattern": "/cashboxes/[0-9]+/registration"
},

"response": {
  "status": 200,
  "jsonBody": {}
}
```

I want, that input number [0-9]+ replace into body with name of query param.

As I see it:

```
URL: http://baseUrl/cashboxes/1/registration

"response": {
  "status": 200,
  "jsonBody": {
     "cashboxes_id": "1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible through the mechanism of [Response Templates](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/). This allows you to use many of the request meta data items, but also the body itself through its support for Handlebars templating.

In your example it would be like this:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/cashboxes/[0-9]+/registration/[0-9]+"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "jsonBody": {
            "status": "status one",
            "URLpat1": "{{request.path.[1]}}",
            "URLpat2": "{{request.path.[3]}}"

        },
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "transformers": ["response-template"]
    }
}
```

And when the this GET request is sent:

```
http://localhost:9999/cashboxes/1000/registration/2000
```

Then this response is received:

```
{
    "status": "status one",
    "URLpat1": "1000",
    "URLpat2": "2000"
}
```